# Table Count Comparison For SSIS Healthcheck

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

In our production environment, I have a SSIS package to import from OLTP SQL Server database to Data Warehouse (in SQL Server) and from there another package imports from Data warehouse to a Tabular SSAS database.

For health check reason, I would like to develop a SSIS package to compare table counts between production OLTP, Data warehouse and Tabular databases. I know how to do it for SQL Server databases but have no idea how to calculate table counts of Tabular tables and save the results to a SQL Server table to compare the counts.

Has any body done this? Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: You need to compare number of tables or number of rows within those tables?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using DMVs to Query the SSAS instance:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126299.aspx

```
SELECT * FROM $System.DBSchema_Tables
```